# Computer noob needs help with video format conversion

Tags: video, file-format, video-conversion, mp4, mkv

I need to convert 2 movies from the .MKS format to a .MP4 or .AVI file. How would I do that? I would prefer doing this in a GUI as I am not comfortable with the Command Line Interface.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing Handbrake from terminal (you can open terminal by pressing **Ctrl+Alt+T**)

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake
```

Then open handbrake from Unity Dash or from terminal by typing `ghb`

Handbrake is GUI multimedia converter and will definitely do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Software Center has *Winff* .  It's a GUI for ffmpeg which will git 'er done.